# Azure Log Analytics splitting a huge json log without any corelation ID

Tags: azure

I have a springboot application which is running on AKS(Azure Kubernetes Service). In that app i am trying to print a log (JSON object) which has a character length of 1,00,000.
When i query this in LogAnalytics in Azure, it splits the entire log message in 4 or more entries without any co-relation ID and there is no way I can identify if the split logs belongs to a particular transaction.  the message ID/thread ID, timestamp and other details are printed with first entry. The second entry continues from the point where first log entry gets terminated.

Is there as way we can set the character length of the logEntry column in azure?

The logs are split when the character count of one entry becomes equal to 16384

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the similar question was discussed and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64087056/kubernetes-logs-split-in-kibana)ed on StackOverflow.

> [fluent-plugin-concat](https://github.com/fluent-plugins-nursery/fluent-plugin-concat) did the job combine to one log. solve docker's max log line (of 16Kb) solve long lines in my container logs get split into multiple lines solve max size of the message seems to be 16KB therefore for a message of 85KB the result is that 6 messages were created in different chunks.