# Kubernetes logs split in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana

I have Kubernetes system in Azure and used the following instrustions to install fluent, elasticsearch and kibana: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/fluentd-elasticsearch I am able to see my pods logs in kibana but when i send logs more then 16k chars its just split.

if i send 35k chars . its split into 3 logs.

how can i increase the limit of 1 log? I want to able to see the 36k chars in one log.

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewocJ.png)

Comment: What happens if you send a 36K chars log direclty to kibana? Does it arrive in one piece?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61511736/azure-log-analytics-splitting-a-huge-json-log-without-any-corelation-id   does it look like this?

Comment: @Nick yes just like this!

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/fluent-plugins-nursery/fluent-plugin-concat

did the job combine to one log.
solve docker's max log line (of 16Kb)
solve long lines in my container logs get split into multiple lines
solve max size of the message seems to be 16KB therefore for a message of 85KB the result is that 6 messages were created in different chunks.

Answer (score 0):

I have been [digging this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61360759/logging-with-docker-and-kubernetes-logs-more-than-16k-split-up/61381089#61381089) half a year ago. In short, this is an expected behavior.

Docker chunks log messages at 16K, because of a 16K buffer for log messages. If a message length exceeds 16K, it should be **split** by the json file logger and **merged** at the endpoint.

It looks like the [Docker_mode](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/v/1.3/input/tail#docker_mode) option for Fluentbit might help, but I'm not sure how exactly you are parsing container logs.